# Prevention to Cross Site Scripting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xss, antixsslibrary

I have received one vulnerability effects detail from Acunetix-scan Vulnerability scan.

```
**Request URL**
http://www.example.co/brands/tom-ford-2692.aspx,Gender.Women
```

**Attack details**
    URL encoded GET input Gender.Women was set to F"onmouseover=9QJ0(9526)"
    The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.

I am new for this and have no idea how to recover my site from this vulnerability.
Any reply will be appreciated

Comment: You can get more information on XSS attacks here - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29 and its prevention here - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Comment: have read it, i need to validate request URL's meta characters for vulnerability, but not yet any idea about it..

Answer (score 0):

before rendering any string from user input into HTML page do HTMLEncode(userInputString)

Comment: have done it already but still getting this type alerts.I think it is related with QueryString into mvc, whenever we request through querystring, mvc checks only action name not whole parameter , are those exist or not,if exist then matched or not,so not able to solve it...